# Dimmers and light sources

Tags: discussion

Is this site intended for questions only about electronics as opposed to electrical equipment such as dimmers or light sources?

As english is not my native language I not sure a question about the digital LED dimming standard "[Ledotron](http://ledotron.com/)" will fit here.

So, Go or no go?

Comment: Ledotron is a trade name for DLT, "Digital load side transmission lighting interface" which is being standardised as IEC 62756-1.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends on the nature of your question. If you want to ask something about designing equipment that is compatible with the standard, then [EE.SE](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/) is probably the place to do it. On the other hand, if your question is about installing/using the existing equipment, then [DIY.SE](https://diy.stackexchange.com/) would probably be a better place.